# Google speech-to-text output json file as input to text-to-speech API?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have an audio file containing the monologue for a video.  I don't like the persons voice so I wanted to convert it to a Google Cloud Text-To-Speech voice, specifically the en-GB female voice.

I was able to create the speech-to-text json file using the API, but the output format of the json file isn't compatible with the input json format used by the text-to-speech API.

Is there a way to bridge the output from Google's speech-to-text engine as input to their text-to-speech engine?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to do this automatically.

One thing that comes to my mind is to create a simple script to get the output of the Speech-to-Text API and then format the input for the Text-to-Speech API if you plan to perform this operation usually, if not maybe the easiest thing would be just copying and pasting the output of the Speech-to-Text API to the Text-to-Speech API.